# Do the Beast Sense and Beast Bond spells work on creatures from Conjure Animals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning, animals

The [Beast Sense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beast-sense) and [Beast Bond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beast-bond) spells, as their names imply, require the target to be of type "beast."

Now looking to the [Conjure Animals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-animals) spell, its description says:

> You summon fey spirits that take the form of beasts

which makes it sound like they might simply be fey and not *really* beasts. But then the description goes on to say, of the animals in question:

> Each beast is also considered fey

which makes it sound like each animal is first of all beast, and then supplementally "also" a fey.

So which is it?  Can Beast Sense and Beast Bond work on these creatures, or not?

Comment: Related: [Do fey spirits in the form of creatures from the Conjure Animal Spell count towards creatures one has seen for Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51858/do-fey-spirits-in-the-form-of-creatures-from-the-conjure-animal-spell-count-towa), [Does the fey summoned by Conjure Animals inherit the language of the beast it resembles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94360/does-the-fey-summoned-by-conjure-animals-inherit-the-language-of-the-beast-it-re)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## *Conjure animals* creates things that are both beast and fey

> You summon fey spirits that take the form of **beasts** [...]
>
> Choose one of the following for what appears:
>
> - One **beast** of challenge rating 2 or lower [...]
>
> Each beast is **also considered fey** [...]

The spell makes it clear that these are fey spirits taking the form of beasts. Since they are referred to as beasts, they are considered to be beasts. The spell then tells us specifically that they are **also** considered to be fey. "Also" would be completely nonsensical and unnecessary if the animals were not also beasts.

There are no such things as primary or supplemental creature types. If a creature is described as a certain creature type (or types) it simply is considered to be those types.

#### Any spells  that target beasts and/or fey will work on the creatures

Since *beast bond* and *beast sense* both target beasts and the creatures summoned by *conjure animals* are beasts, then they will both work on them. The fact that the creatures are also considered to be fey has no effect on the situation. In fact, any spell that targets fey will also be able to  target the creatures.

Comment: This is correct. A good comparison is Find Familiar, which indicates the creature's type is celestial, fey, or fiend *instead* of beast. Typically, if an effect is said to work on a creature type, it works if a creature has at least that type. If an effect is said to not work on a creature type (such as cure wounds on an undead), it would not work if the creature has at least that type. I don't believe there is currently an effect that has both a whitelist *and* blacklist for creature types, nor a creature with two types that are whitelisted and blacklisted for the same effect.